# Splitting on "," but not "\,"

Tags: java, regex, parsing, csv

I'm looking for a regular expression to match `,` but ignore `\,` in Java's regex engine. This comes close:

```
[^\\],
```

However, it matches the previous character (in addition to the comma), which won't work.

Perhaps the regular expression approach is the wrong one altogether. I was intending to use `String.split()` to parse a simple CSV file (can't use an external library) with escaped commas.

Comment: Ah, definitely a duplicate. Sorry, I missed it when searching for solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You need a [negative look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here:

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?<![^\\\\]\\\\),");
```

Note that you need 4 backslashes there. First escape the backslash for Java string literal. And then again escape both the backslashes for regex.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was reading up on lookaheads before I gave up and asked this question.

Comment: This fails on a string like `Split\\,this`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker. oops. missed the edge case. Will edit the regex. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, so what about `Don't split\\\,this`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker. Ah! if only Java regex supported variable length look-behinds. Still thinking of a way.